# Imagecopy merge Issue

Tags: php, gd

```
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('GreenAppleMerge80.png');
$image_2 = $image_1;
imagealphablending($image_1, true);
imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 40, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
imagepng($image_1, 'final.png');
```

The above code is written to merge two GreenAppleMerge80.png  into final.png

[image: Green.png]

[image: final.png]

However i am not satisfied with final.png and want the right apple to visible fully and 50% of the left apple, where right apple wil be 50% on top of left apple.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a GD resource that can hold both apples.

```
$imgBig = imagecreate(120 , 80);
```

You get the PNG exactly as shown. You don't need image_2. It is the same resource.

```
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('GreenAppleMerge80.png');
imagealphablending($image_1, true);
imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
```

Then you copy the right half of the apple into the big picture.

```
imagecopy($imgBig, $image_1, 80, 0, 40, 0, 40, 80);
```

Then you create your 2nd picture and copy it into the "imgBig".

```
imagecopy($image_1, $image_1, 40, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80);

imagecopy($imgBig, $image_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80);

imagepng($imgBig, 'final.png');
```

The solution is not particularly nice. But works for me with your apple picture.